# Replacing Motherboard and Processor

Tags: cpu, motherboard, compatibility

I'm planning to replace the motherboard and processor on my Linux box. I know that the two need to be compatible with each other and the RAM, but are there compatibility issues to worry about with other parts?

Answer (score 2):

yes!! you should look at your motherboard first on what is the compatible parts for it, so that you can buy the right parts for your computer..

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. What parts need to be compatible?

Comment: parts?it should be the power supply, the video cards, memory cards..

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer, but usually, as iDarine pointed out, everything from power supply to CPU, video card, memory, hard drives, etc. are impacted by your choice of motherboard.